# Is It possible if i add crystal report in my .Net DLL and this DLL use in my .net Core Project for reporting purpose

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, crystal-reports

I have .Net DLL  it's containing Crystal report functionality it's working fine in my all .net project with some modifications. Now, I want to use the same DLL in my .Net Core Project for reporting purpose

Comment: Could you please put a specific question you have?

Comment: very simple I want to use Crystal report in my .net core project so  .net core directly not support it but .net core support .net 4.5  DLL we can include the .net 4.5 DLL in .net core   and  .net 4.5 support Crystal reports

Comment: in this way we can achive crystal reports functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it should work. You can add reference .Net framework DLL into .Net Core project. So try doing some POC on generating reports.

1. Try to generate static report which will does not have any database connectivity or dynamic datasource.
2. Try to generate simple report with database connectivity with ODBC. I am sure ODBC should work on .Net Core as well.

~Nilesh